# How to make a bootable USB and install Windows 10 using only Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, bootloader, liveusb

So I want to make a dual boot installation with Windows 10 and Ubuntu. In order to do that, I need to install Windows 10 first. The problem is that when I create an installation USB with a Windows 10 image (taken from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)) and try to boot from it, I get the following error:

```
error: unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I tried creating an installation USB using `dd if=/path/to/windows/installer/image.iso of=/dev/sdd`. I also tried `woeusb` utility.

The questions are:

1. How do I properly create a Windows 10 USB installer and boot from it, provided that I don't have access to a Windows machine?
2. Why do I even get a message from grub? My current understanding is that when you boot from an USB, then whatever bootloader that is on the USB should be used.

Comment: try using https://rufus.ie/

Comment: Re: 2. Yes, correct. It means the media isn't properly made. MKUSB works for the newer Microsoft ISOs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a bootable Windows 10 USB drive (UEFI) from Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1017756/create-a-bootable-windows-10-usb-drive-uefi-from-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make a partition on your USB and format it in an appropriate filesystem, for Windows NTFS would work. Probably it's a good idea to use **parted** for creating the disk label anew (msdos or gpt)

Install the tool for working with NTFS and format the newly created partition:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdXX -o
```

You can't use **dd** for writing Windows on USB because it's ISO is not isohybrid. So the only option that I'm aware of is using **woeusb**

Comment: If you still experience troubles with USB maybe this will be a good workaround for you - https://superuser.com/questions/457640/how-can-i-install-windows-7-without-dvd-or-usb-on-linux/1124958#1124958